# asp.net core ajax get

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

I am making a simple jquery ajax get request. The first request works great. However, any subsequent returns the error **431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)**. It seems asp.net core is adding the headers that are quite large (see pic)

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance for the help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbSxP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `TempData` uses a cookie-based provider, which means each piece of data you add goes out as a cookie. It looks like you've added so much here that the header is now too large. The easiest solution is to use session state as a `TempData` provider, instead. Then, you'll just have one session cookie going out, regardless of how much data you set in `TempData`. In `ConfigureServices` add:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

services.AddSession();
```

And then in `Configure`:

```
app.UseSession();
app.UseMvc();
```

You'll like also want to configure session to use a persistent store like Redis or SQL Server, rather than the default of in-memory, but that's not directly relevant to the use of `TempData`.